# If I add a product to my cart, is there a way to track that sku on all pages?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, simple-product, sku, array

I have been trying this to retrieve them and it works fine on Product detail pages.

```
$data = array();
// PDP
if ($module === 'catalog' && $controller === 'product' && $action === 'view') {

            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $product  = Mage::registry('current_product');
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');

            // Product(s) IDs
            $data['u2'] = $product->getSku();
```

I've noticed it pulls various styles from configurable and there is lots of them which means there will be lots of style numbers (only shows one).

My question is... is there a way to pull all the style numbers and display them for all various colors in a configurable or just pull the simple sku?

I hope that makes sense. I'll eagerly await for feedback. Thank you.

```
Magento ver. 1.13.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this->

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$sku = array();
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {

   $sku[] = $item->getSku();  

}
print_r($sku);
```

Comment: Will this work on all pages? My code above currently works on PDP pages.

Comment: in which file you have added this code?

Comment: Your code or my code? My code is part of a module I built.

Comment: if you want this to work on all pages  you have to add this code in a file which is called on every page.